# Views: linking fields from different content type

Tags: views, 7

I created a content type: Battle and Content type: Map.
In the content type battle I have fields "name", "date", "image", "text".
While in the content type of the map I can add one or more photos.
I would like to be able to bind fields between them, so that with a view, I can extrapolate the result so:
"date", "name of the battle," pictures of the map.

I think in the content type: Map, I expect a field to enter the link to the content type: Battle, which I need, but I do not know how.

Comment: Hope  reference module is you are searching for  http://drupal.org/project/references